# Cutplace : Conditional check for empty fields

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to create a configuration with the tool 'cutplace' (http://roskakori.github.io/cutplace) to check a csv file for empty fields based on a particular field not being empty.

So the rule is something like this : if field #6 is not empty, then fields #8, #9, and #10 should not be empty.

However, I don't seem to be able to find this option in the documentation to do this. Would much appreciate some advice on how I might be able to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

in `icd/custom/custom_cutplace_checks.py` (make sure there is a **init**.py in that directory)

```
from cutplace import checks
from cutplace import ranges

class SixEightNineTen(checks.AbstractCheck):
    """Check that entries of have other fields if six is active"""
    def __init__(self, description, rule, availableFieldNames, location=None):
        self.as_super = super(SixEightNineTen, self)
        self.as_super.__init__(description, rule, availableFieldNames, location)
        self.reset()

    def checkRow(self, rowMap, location):
        if(rowMap["Field6"]!=''):
            if(any([rowMap["Field8"]=='',rowMap["Field9"]=='',rowMap["Field10"]==''):
                raise checks.CheckError(location)
```

At the tail of your .icd file:

```
,Checks,,,,,
C,filename must be unique,IsUnique,Filename,,,
C,MD5 must be unique,IsUnique,MD5,,,
C,"field6 implies 8,9,10",custom_cutplace_checks.SixEightNineTen
```

Comment: Thanks Jeremey. Will test this and revert.

Comment: When I run this I get the error : "ERROR:cutplace:cannot read ICD file 'validate1.icd': close() called during concurrent operation on the same file object."

Comment: And other times I get the error : "ERROR:cutplace:cannot find class for check custom_cutplace_checks.SixEightNineTen: related class is SixEightNineTenCheck but must be one of: 'DistinctCountCheck' or 'IsUniqueCheck'"

Comment: put your files in a github repo along with your csv

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Here you go : https://github.com/sukritd/csv-parse-cutplace2

Comment: Hi @Jeremy, were you by any chance able to have a look at the files I uploaded? Thanks again!

Comment: Can you try it again using cutplace version 0.6.8? Version 0.7 added  a few concurrency features that didn't turn out so well.